# Germany Blue Card: Criminal Check + ZAB Certification + Attestation

Tags: germany, blue-card

1. For applying for Germany EU Blue card or job seekers visa, Do I need to submit background FBI check[USA] or police report[India] or my credit report etc.
2. For ZAB certification, are official sealed transcripts are enough [degree and mark sheets] to be sent.
3. For ZAB certification [BE degreee], do we need official transcripts of higher education also or just photocopies.
4. For ZAB certification - Can I send in Notarized photocopies instead of university transcripts.